# how to validate digit in javascript

Tags: javascript

How to validate these conditions in javacript?

1. Minimum of 3 digits,
2. Maximum of 5 digits,
3. Decimal point after the third digit

Correct values samples:123 , 123.1, 123.55.

Comment: Should `123.` (decimal point without decimals) be accepted or rejected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `RegExp`

```
/^(\d{3})(\.\d{1,2})?$/.test(number+'');
```

---

#### Explanation

`\d{3})` means any digits, exactly 3 times

`(\.\d{1,2})?` is more complicated. It means after the three digits, there can be: *A decimal, a digit 1-2 times*

---

#### Tests

- **123** -> *true*
- **123.4** -> *true*
- **123.** -> *false*
- **123.45** -> *true*
- **123.456** -> *false*
- **12** -> *false*
- **1234** -> *false*

---

This accepts both **a `string`** and  **a `number`**

Comment: You don't need to put `\d` in square brackets.

Comment: He said minimum of 3 digits, your RE allows 1 digit.

Comment: Why do you need `=== number+''`? `.match()` returns `false` if the RE doesn't match.

Comment: And shouldn't you have `^` and `$` anchors?

Answer (score 0):

**Regex:** /^\d{3}(?:.\d{1,2})?$/

```
var pattern = /^\d{3}(?:.\d{1,2})?$/;
pattern.test(number);
```